# What is best way to return object permission with instance using Django Rest Framework and django-guardian

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-guardian

I'm using Django Rest Framework and django-guardian (for per object permissions), what is best way to return object permission with instance.

For example now request "/api/v1/objects/" returns:

```
 {
  "id":0,
  "category": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "address": "string",
 }
```

but I want return object with permissions:

```
{
  "id":0,
  "category": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "address": "string",
  "permissions":
  {
     "change": true,
     "delete": true
  } 
}
```

this would be useful, for example, if the user does not have the right to delete the object, on the frontend do not display the delete button.

Below is project structure:

```
#Model
class Object(models.Model):
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, default=None)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

#Serializer   
class ObjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   is_folder = BooleanField(read_only=True)


   class Meta:
      model = Object
      fields = ('id', 'category', 'is_folder', 'name', 'address')

#ViewSet
class ObjectsViewSet(BaseViewSet, RetrieveModelMixin, ListModelMixin, CreateModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin,
                 DestroyModelMixin):
    queryset = Object.objects
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, ObjectPermission)

    def get_queryset(self):

     queryset = super(ObjectsViewSet, self).get_queryset()

    return queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)

#Permission
class ObjectPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in ['GET']:
            return request.user.has_perm('view_object')
        if request.method in ['POST']:
            return request.user.has_perm('add_object')
        if request.method in ['PUT', 'PATCH']:
            return request.user.has_perm('change_object')
        if request.method in ['DELETE']:
            return request.user.has_perm('delete_object')
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in ['GET']:
            return request.user.has_perm('view_object', obj)
        if request.method in ['PUT', 'PATCH']:
            return request.user.has_perm('change_object', obj)
        if request.method in ['DELETE']:
            return request.user.has_perm('delete_object', obj)
        return False
```

Comment: You should be overriding `BasePermission.has_object_permission` for object level permissions in DRF